# Which folder does JavaScript go into when doing a Spring Boot application with Maven on Intellij?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

This is my first attempt at combining Java and JavaScript, languages I can use independently but never together. The main application is in Java, but I wanted to add dynamic manipulation of the DOM.

```
I tried: resource/static/index.js
I tried resource/templates/index.js
```

Neither worked. Where else would a JavaScript folder go? I have CSS in static/main.css, and HTML in templates/list.html.

This may be such an easy question that I can't find an answer online. Do I need to create a folder for JavaScript? Where would that go?

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd recommend using https://start.spring.io/ to create your project for Spring Boot.

Second - We need to know if you are using Maven/Gradle or what?

Typically, you'll put them in `src/main/webapp` if you're using mvn or gradle.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Maven with Intellij IDE.

Comment: It works now. I tried putting it in a folder in main, as well as by itself in the main folder, but it ended up working by placing it in the static folder. I'm not sure why it didn't work the first time. Thanks again.